# SQL Multiple queries on different columns

Tags: sql

I have several queries with results of just one column each, and I want to combine those into a table. Please add the **general** method, as I have multiple queries from different tables which I need to retrieve data from.

Example:

**Table X**

| ID | time | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-06-12 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-06-02 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-05-21 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-04-01 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-03-01 | 2 |

**Table Y**

| ID | time | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-06-12 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-06-02 | 3 |
| 4 | 2021-05-21 | 3 |
| 5 | 2021-04-01 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-03-01 | 4 |

**query1**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableX AS A 
WHERE A.type = 1
AND A.date BETWEEN '01-05-2021' AND '20-07-2021'
```

**query2**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableX AS B
WHERE B.type = 2 
AND B.date BETWEEN '01-05-2021' AND '20-07-2021'
```

**query3** (exemplifying)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableY AS C 
WHERE C.type = 3
AND C.date BETWEEN '01-03-2021' AND '20-07-2021'
```

There are multiple queries I want to retrieve in the following format:

| query1 | query2 | query3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: Why don't you use simple group by

Comment: Can you exemplify? thanks.

Comment: How many such tables you have?

Comment: I have 5 in this scenario and I might have more in future reports. I am looking for the general method.

Comment: If more tables are involved best is table variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of whatever generic queries, you could combine them like this and hope that the optimizer does a good job to reduce the number of scans.

```sql
select
    (...query1...) as query1,
    (...query2...) as query2,
    (...query3...) as query3;
```

i.e. with your queries

```sql
select
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableX AS A WHERE A.type = 1 AND A.date BETWEEN '01-05-2021' AND '20-07-2021') as query1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableX AS B WHERE B.type = 2 AND B.date BETWEEN '01-05-2021' AND '20-07-2021') as query2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableY AS C WHERE C.type = 3 AND C.date BETWEEN '01-03-2021' AND '20-07-2021') as query3;
```

Under Oracle you must add `from dual`.
**Edit**

```sql
select t1.month_period as m, a, b, c, d, e, f
from
  (values (11, 12, 1), (13, 14, 2)) as t1(a, b, month_period)  
left join
  (values (21, 22, 1), (23, 24, 2)) as t2(c, d, month_period) 
  on t1.month_period = t2.month_period
left join
  (values (31, 32, 1), (33, 34, 2)) as t3(e, f, month_period)
  on t1.month_period = t3.month_period;
```

The `values` expressions stand for query examples. Result:

| m | a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 12 | 21 | 22 | 31 | 32 |
| 2 | 13 | 14 | 23 | 24 | 33 | 34 |

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I need. However, Microsoft Server Management Studio returns an error is I do just select and add the queries, which is why I asked for the proper method to generalise. How can I continue the query?

Comment: This works fine under Postgresql, SQLite and Oracle. What is the error that you get? And you don't omit the parenthesis, do you?

Comment: It is working now, it was my punctuation incorrect. Many thanks. Would you be able to present the general method to retrieve multiple rows for multiple periods of time when running same queries? I would also like a new column with the period of time for each row

Comment: For example, monthly stats with 12 rows for the last 12 months

Comment: In this case you should `join` the queries on `month` i.e. period of time column.

Comment: Can you exemplify?

Comment: I have edited my answer. BTW your case looks like a `lateral join` candidate.

Answer (score 1):

I hope below query should do

```
SELECT 
    A.type, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    tableX AS A 
WHERE 
    A.date BETWEEN '01-05-2021' AND '20-07-2021'
GROUP BY 
    A.type
```

| type | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |

Comment: Edited the query to exemplify why I needed that exact format. There will also be more rows in the final result, for different periods I set, but until then, I am looking for a way to actually have multiple SQL queries displaying on separate columns, rather than fixing one query. When there are too many, these tricks will not work any longer. Could you update the query? Thanks.

Comment: How do you provide multiple periods? May be from another table

Comment: If things are too many and more tables involved, you would have to insert output in temp table or table variable

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for makes very little sense.

You can do this:

```
SELECT type, count(type) FROM tableX
WHERE time between '2021-05-01' AND '2021-07-20'
GROUP BY type;
```

To get this:

| type | count(type) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

Comment: The reason I wanted it in that format is that I have multiple queries to combine, from different tables, and also will need multiple rows for of that final table, with different time intervals. When you give it to me like this, I cannot apply it when I have another query from a different table.

Comment: Can you please give your other tables queries? Is it that first query cones from tablex while second from tabley?

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution

```
SELECT SUM(case when type =1 and time BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2021-07-20' THEN 1 else 0 end) AS query1,
       SUM(case when type =2 and time BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2021-07-20' THEN 1 else 0 end) AS query2
       FROM   tableX
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also adjust it so that I can have multiple periods of time and add more rows to the result according to them? For example, monthly counts for the last 12 months

Comment: Also, would you be able to generalise so that I have other tables there as well? I actually have many tables which are not stored as they are, but queries to generate them in the correct form.

Comment: This query is the answer to your question. I need more details to answer your above comment. Thanks